# Higher starting gravity

Tags: specific-gravity, final-gravity, alcohol-content

Is it true to get a higher S.G. you can by add extra Suger and fermentables like extra suger DME. I 'm trying to find a way to raise, The S.G and F.G
to get a higher ABV.

Answer (score 2):

One can add any (sensible) soluble substance to get a higher S.G. If the substance is not fermentable then one also generally gets a higher F.G. If one wants a higher ABV then one adds a fermentable substance to the initial brew. This can be done by adding sugar, glucose, golden syrup, molasses (eg.for stouts) candisugar (eg Belgian ales) and malt extract (dry or liquid).

If one wants a higher F.G and ABV then a good option is to use malt extract as only a proportion is fermentable. What ferments boosts the ABV what remains boosts the FG. If one wants a higher S.G and ABV but a commensurately lower FG then use sugars (glucose/dextrose being a nice option).

Comment: Pete am I understanding you correctly. I would add whatever fermentables into the wort in the beginning. Is there a specific amount that I can and without hurting the Beer?

Comment: There are limits in adding sugar to wort and expecting it to ferment to alcohol. The basic limit is the attenuation rate of the yeast - essentially the max ABV that the yeast will ferment to. Some ferment to only 8% others to 10% and other to 14%. Beyond that it gets a bit "hit and miss". Adding sugar to go beyond that point will result in strong but sweet beer. There is also a higher osmotic point that will prevent most things from fermenting a sugar solution (bacteria included) and to imagine that think "jam" . That has such a high percentage of sugar that it is in effect preserved by it.